# Run PyCharm project outside of PyCharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I have a PyCharm project which uses a virtual env and its own site-packages and I want to be able to run it without needing to open PyCharm everytime.

My current naive solution is runing a batch file which launches the python in the venv and the main script `python.exe ../../PythonFiles/Main.pyw`. The issue with this is that the console will stay open as its running from a batch process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate your virtual python environment by this command

```
source activate yourenvname
```

then change the directory and go to source directory ../../PythonFiles/ and type

```
 start pythonw Main.pyw
```

This will help to start the python script in the background & If you don't want to run in the background and keep terminal open remove pyw change it to py extension then run it.